# A house is guarded by two alarms

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I am trying to wrap my head around the following problem
A house is guarded by two alarms.

If Alarm 1 fires, p(theft) = 80%
If Alarm 2 fires, p(theft) = 70%

If both alarms fire at the same time, what is the probability of a theft?

- Assuming both alarms are independent
- Assuming there is some dependence between the alarms

It seems simple, but I just can't seem to get it for some reason. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to say, for example, is

$$ P(\text{theft} \mid \text{alarm } 1) = 0.8 $$

....

Answer (score 2):

If independent, the probability that both alarms fire erroneously is the product of 20% (probability of error for the first one) and 30% (probability of error for the second one), which is 6%. You can do this thanks to the well known rule: probability that two independent events both occur = product of the two single probabilities. Therefore, the probability that at least one alarm fires  appropriately (probability of theft) is 100-6=94%.

If not independent, the method to calculate the probability of theft is similar, but it is necessary to know the degree of dependence, i.e. the conditional probability (probability that one alarm fires provided that the other fires).

Comment: Thanks, could you please see my comment below regarding this answer? To put another way, we can reverse the problem, and the alarms light green when safe. We can say P(No theft|A1) = 0.2, P(No theft|A2) = 0.3 (which follows directly from the input). Now, P(Theft|A1,A2) is the probability that both safety alarms are wrong, and P(Theft|A1, A2) = 1 - 0.7 * 0.8 = 0.44, so something seems missing still.

Comment: You cannot say that P(No theft|A1) = 0.2 and P(No theft|A2) = 0.3, referring A1 and A2 to the safety green. In fact, 0.2 and 0.3 are not the probabilities of no theft when the alarms do not fire. They are the probabilities of no theft when the alarms fire.